# How display available Wi-Fi and cells access point with google maps API

Tags: google-api

I want to display all Wi-Fi access point and all cellular access point with Google Maps API in a limited area.
I have a Google API key.

Answer (score 0):

From an Google account manager:

> Google does not have/offer the WiFi access points data in the APIs
>
> WiGLE, or (Wireless Geographic Logging Engine), is a website for
>   collecting information about the different wireless hotspots around
>   the world. Users can register on the website and upload hotspot data
>   like GPS. So I believe WiGLE's users upload the location of various
>   WiFi access points. Then WiGLE uses that information to place it on a
>   Google Map.

Answer (score 0):

Q1) In which programming language do you want t accomplish that?

Q2) Does it have to be a Google Map? There are other free Webmap services, e.g. CartoDB, Esri, ... where you don't have to send an API Key.

In any case, here is what I did:

Get an API Key for the Wigle API and download the JSON responses from the `/api/v2/network/search` endpoint, in 100-record batches. See https://api.wigle.net/swagger#/Network_search_and_information_tools/search_2 for details.

Read in the JSON responses and create a table. Coordinates are in the `trilat` and `trilong` columns.

Plot the map, perhaps with [Leaflet](https://leafletjs.com/)